# how to code to find probability in java or php

Tags: java, php, probability

I want to make a program like the example below.

```
input : 2
output : 
(1) , (2);
(1,2), (2,2);

input : 3 
output :
(1),(2),(3);
(1,2),(1,3),(2,3);
(1,2,3)
```

The formula is 2^<sup>n-1</sup>.

I have tried only using for only. I want to get the all possibility.

like :
(1),(2);
(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,1),

Comment: Research enumerating all possible permutations. There are abundant examples online.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. We will not do all the work for you.

Comment: The formula is not  2^n-1.!

Comment: Im sorry. Im still so bad at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom function on `PHP`:

```
$inputValues = range(1,3); //here you set your input(2 or 3 or what you want)

$result = array();

function variations($inputValues, $level, &$result, $current = array()) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($inputValues); $i++) {
        $new = array_merge($current, array($inputValues[$i]));
        if($level == 1) {
          sort($new);
            if (!in_array($new, $result)) {
                $result[] = $new;          
            }
        } else {
            variations($inputValues, $level - 1, $result, $new);
        }
    }
}
for ($i = 0; $i<count($inputValues); $i++) {
    variations($inputValues, $i+1, $result);
    }

foreach ($result as $arr) {
    echo '('.join(",", $arr) . ')';
}
```

`Result is:`

```
(1)(2)(3)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,2)(2,3)(3,3)(1,1,1)(1,1,2)(1,1,3)(1,2,2)(1,2,3)(1,3,3)(2,2,2)(2,2,3)(2,3,3)(3,3,3)
```

Comment: Thank you.that is more than enough for me. Thank you :D @sergio